# What is the advantages of use the new "defer" instead of a *ngIf in Angular 17?

Tags: angular

Angular recents announced v17 of Angular, that will have a new solution for lazy loading components, called **Deferred Loading**.

What is the advantages of use `defer` instead of `*ngIf`?

**Deferred Loading:**

```
{#defer when condition}
  <app-my-component />
{/defer}
```

***ngIf:**

```
<app-my-component *ngIf="condition"> </app-my-acomponent>
```

Comment: `@if (condition)`  is the equivalent of `ngIf`. there is no obvious advantage apart from the thing that this piece if processed at a compile time, and you don't need a common module in the scout to be able to use `ngIf` directive. `@defer` is on the other part pretty powerful api that provides the capability of ergonomic handlin of lazy loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new feature is called Deferrable views.

A deferrable view is wrapped in a `@defer{}` block.

This allows the angular compiler to transform the static import of the component into a dynamic import. By doing this your bundler will be able to lazy-load the component wrapped by the `@defer` block.

There are 2 main differences with `ngIf` or the `@if` block :

1. `NgIf`/`@if` doesn't lazy-load.
2. A deferrable view cannot be reverted. It won't allow you to toggle a component depending on boolean values like the if block does. If you want that behavior you'll have to wrap the `@defer` with an `@if`.

You'll get more info on the [new docs](https://angular.dev/guide/defer) !